# If $G$ has a maximal subgroup that is normal, finite and abelian, then $G$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, contest-math, abelian-groups, maximal-subgroup

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be an *abelian* and *normal* subgroup. If
>   $H$ is *finite* and *maximal*, prove that $G$ is finite.

What I tried :

Assume $H=\{e,h_2,\cdots,h_{n}\}$. As for each $j$, we have $H\leq C_G(h_j)\leq G$, by maximality, we have $H=C_G(h_j)$ or $h_j\in Z(G)$. WLOG, suppose $\{h_2,\cdots,h_k\}\subset Z(G)$ and for $j\geq k+1$, $C_G(h_j)=H$.

For each $g\in G$, we have $gH=Hg$, i.e. $\{g,gh_2,\cdots,gh_k\}=\{g,h_2g,\cdots,h_kg\}$ and $\{gh_{k+1},\cdots,gh_n\}=\{h_{k+1}g,\cdots,h_ng\}$.

Indeed, for any $g$ and its conjugacy class members, we have assigned one bijection on the set $\{k+1,\cdots,n\}$, that is $h_{k+1}g=gh_{\sigma(k+1)},\cdots,h_{n}g=gh_{\sigma(n)}$

I'm a little mixed up to continue! I think we must prove that $H$ is of finite index and then we're done ...

Comment: can you tell where is this problem from?

Comment: It's from Iran's NOET Mathematical Olympiad for University students, held in Aug 2015.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** The question has been edited to omit that $H$ is of finite index of $G$. So we first prove that $G/H$ is finite.

Let $H\subset G$ a finite normal maximal subgroup. For all $g\in G-H$ we have $\langle g\rangle H=G$ because $H$ is normal and maximal. The [second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem) tells us that
$$G/H = \langle g\rangle H/H\cong \langle g\rangle/(\langle g\rangle\cap H).$$
Of course the latter is cyclic, so it is either finite or isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. But if it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ then
$$\langle g\rangle\cong\Bbb{Z}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\langle g\rangle\cap H=\{1\},$$
from which it follows that $\langle g^2\rangle H$ is a subgroup of $\langle g\rangle H=G$ strictly containing $H$, i.e. satisfying
$$H\subsetneq \langle g^2\rangle H\subsetneq G,$$
contradicting the maximality of $H$. This shows that $G/H$ is finite.

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29) we now have
$$|G|=|H|\cdot|G/H|.$$
So $G$ is finite because $H$ and $G/H$ are.

Note that this doesn't use the fact that $H$ is abelian.

Comment: Sorry, That's not of finite index. I edited it

Comment: I thought Lagranges's theorem starts with "For any finite group $G$".

Comment: @scaaahu Not necessarily (though that's what's done in elementary courses). It holds for infinite cardinals as well. For example: If any two of the three cardinalities (in the equation) is finite so is the third. If any two of $G$, $H$, and $G/H$ are countably infinite, so is the third. And so on.

Comment: @M.Vinay Yes, you're right. But, it's not clear to me where did this answer show $|G/H|$ is finite before using Lagranges's theorem?

Comment: @scaaahu Ah, I see. From the first comment on this answer, I gathered that the question had been edited and the original said $H$ was of finite index in $G$.

Comment: Great, It was really beautiful that for proving finiteness of the group $G/H$, you made a wise choice of some another isomorphic group !